# Core Data - Distinct Results not working in fetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have spend hours trying to figure the following out...

I have the following Core Data fetchResultsController in my iPhone App which does not return me a distinct set of values despite setting the following in my code...

```
// Only distinct values
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
```

The following is the whole fetchResultController ...

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CardMessage"inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

// Set the properties to fetch
NSArray *propertiesToFetch = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"category", nil];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:propertiesToFetch];

// Only distinct values
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];

// Order the output
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"category" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                        initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                        sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                        cacheName:@"Master"];

aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `propertiesToFetch` array contains a string. It should contain an `NSPropertyDescription`. (In this case it will be a subclass thereof, `NSAttributeDescription`.)

```
NSArray *propertiesToFetch = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
   [entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"category"], 
   nil];
```

(modern Objective-C)

```
NSArray *propertiesToFetch = @[entity.propertiesByName[@"category"]];
```

If you still get double entries, just use `NSSet` to get unique values.

```
NSSet *uniqueProperties = [NSSet setWithArray:resultsArray];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it still returns all the rows in the entity

Comment: You can use NSSet. See above.

Comment: Cheers had to use NSSet ... a little confused why [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES]; did not work... PS ... It seems to work as a general fetch request...

Comment: If you use NSSet, have to use array for population(in case of fetchedResultsController) of the tableview, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Note both the remarks from the setPropertiesToFetch documentation:

1. You must set the entity for the fetch request before setting this value, otherwise NSFetchRequest throws an NSInvalidArgumentException exception.
2. This value is only used if resultType is set to NSDictionaryResultType.

Note that the default for resultType is NSManagedObjectResultType.